# how to list an array with cgi.parse_qs in python?

Tags: python, arrays

```
import cgi

data = 'next=/contact/200/106260296&next=/contact/200/106260296&next=/contact/200/106260296&next=/contact/200/106260296&'

x = cgi.parse_qs(data)

next_list = x['next']
```

I am stuck with how to get all the 'next' with something like for y in x or similar.

Any ideas?

Comment: OK, I don't get it. Your code, as posted, is working perfectly for me.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/AdamG/6211210

Comment: Now I also don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import cgi

data = 'next=/contact/200/106260296&next=/contact/200/106260296&next=/contact/200/106260296&next=/contact/200/106260296&'

x = cgi.parse_qs(data)

next_list = x['next']

for i in range(len(x['next'])) :
    print x['next'][i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing another library, you can use plain old list slicing:

```
data = 'next=/contact/200/106260296&next=/contact/200/106260296&next=/contact/200/106260296&next=/contact/200/106260296&'

next_list = [x[:-1] for x in data.split('next=')[1:]]
```

Now `next_list` looks like this: `['/contact/200/106260296', '/contact/200/106260296', '/contact/200/106260296', '/contact/200/106260296']`.

Comment: For the case of non strict parsing, one might encounter a query string in the form of `next=1&foo=next=2&bar=3`. So the `split` should be executed using `&` as its delimiter. See the implementation of `urlparse.parse_qs` (which, in turn, uses `urlparse.parse_qsl`) at http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/urlparse.py

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [j.split('/')[1:] for j in
           [e.split('/contact')[1] for e in cgi.parse_qs(data)['next']]
          ]
```

Then you can do something like:

```
for x, y in my_list:
    print x, y
```

Output:

```
200 106260296
200 106260296
200 106260296
200 106260296
```